# how to solve "Protocol ... can only be used as a generic constraint..."

Tags: swift, protocols

Consider this fragment of code:

```
public protocol Evaluable {
    typealias ReturnType
    func eval(s: State) -> ReturnType
}

protocol AlgebraicExpr : Evaluable {
}

public struct Const : AlgebraicExpr {
    var value: Int = 0

    public func eval(s: State) -> Int {
        return value
    }
}

public struct Add : AlgebraicExpr {
    let a, b: AlgebraicExpr

    public func eval(s: State) -> Int {
        return a.eval() + b.eval()
    }
}
```

it is invalid because `Add` cannot have an `AlgebraicExpr` variable.

But I really need `Add` to store two `AlgebraicExpr`s. How would you solve this in Swift?

For completeness, `State` is just a struct, for example:

```
public struct State {
    var env = Dictionary<String, Int>()

    init(_ d: Dictionary<String, Int> = [:]) {
        env = d
    }

    subscript(s: String) -> Int? {
        get {return env[s]}
        set {env[s] = newValue}
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `State` above?

Comment: Please show us a working and verifiable example (hence including some minimal version of `State`), it helps us to (try to) help you.

Comment: added the implementation of `State`

Comment: I added a way for `Add` to encompass the objects, but did it through an edit and wanted to ping you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't store two protocols that rely on `Self`, or a `typealias` because when abstracted as a protocol, the functionality is undetermined.  Type `Evaluable` has no real meaning without understanding the value of `ReturnType`, so it's not possible for the system to function logically and understand what should be returned.

Take for instance something like this (not valid)

```
let thing: Evaluable = ...
let result = thing.eval(state) // What should return type be?
```

The return type can't be inferred through the protocol alone, it requires an implementation by a specified type that gives more knowledge about its behavior by defining the `typealias ReturnType`

The reason these can function as generic constraints is that the implementation can be inferred through the generic parameters.

```
func genericConstrained<T: Evaluable>(evaluable: T, state: State) -> T.ReturnType {
    return evaluable.eval(state)
}
```

In this example, when we call `genericConstrained` on a particular conforming object, all of its other functionality can be inferred.

**tl;dr**

If however, you also constrain your package, you could do as you wish:

```
public struct Add<ExpressionType : AlgebraicExpr> : AlgebraicExpr {
    let a, b: ExpressionType

    public func eval(s: State) -> ExpressionType.ReturnType {
        return a.eval() + b.eval()
    }
}
```

Then use like

```
let add: Add<SomeConformingType> = ...
```