# Exposing a Realm List as a (read-only) RandomAccessCollection

Tags: swift, generics, realm, type-erasure

I have a set of Realm models that I want to be writable within the module, and read-only outside the module.

I started with a hierarchy of classes (an organizational hierarchy, not inheritance) that looked more or less like this:

```
@objcMembers class Section: Object {
    dynamic var number: Int = 0
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let subsections = List<Subsection>()
}
```

It was fairly straightforward to get the visibility I wanted for the classes themselves and for the Realm-managed `dynamic var` properties:

```
@objcMembers public class Section: Object {
    public internal(set) dynamic var number: Int = 0
    public internal(set) dynamic var name: String = ""
    // ...
}
```

However, the child `Lists` present more of a problem. As it is, the list is declared `let`, so the field itself is read-only; but Realm's `List` itself is mutable. After some digging through the Realm source and a few typical false starts ([trying to use protocols with associated types as return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755436/how-to-solve-protocol-can-only-be-used-as-a-generic-constraint), etc.), I hit on wrapping the `Lists` (which conform to `RandomAccessCollection`) in `AnyRandomAccessCollection`:

```
internal let _subsections = List<Subsection>()

public func subsections() -> AnyRandomAccessCollection<Subsection> {
  return AnyRandomAccessCollection(_subsections)
}
```

When I try to update my unit tests, some of which were accessing the `List` with `Int` indices:

```
// Good
let subsections: List<Subsection> = section.subsections
let subsection0: Subsection = subsections[0]
```

I get

```
// Bad
let subsections: AnyRandomAccessCollection<Subsection> = section.subsections()
let subsection0: Subsection = subsections[0]
```

> **cannot subscript a value of type 'AnyRandomAccessCollection<Subsection>' with an index of type 'Int'**

I'm fairly new to Swift and still being constantly led astray by my Java and C# generics background, but it seemed like the underlying problem was that `Collection` declares two associated types, `Element` and `Index`, but `AnyCollection` only provides `Element` as a generic parameter. After some more digging I found `AnyIndex`, and hit on the following:

```
let subsections: AnyRandomAccessCollection<Subsection> = section.subsections()
let subsection0: Subsection = subsections[AnyIndex(0)]
```

This works, the tests pass, but it seems pretty bananas. It's not obvious to me *why* it works (would it work if the underlying `List` wasn't subscripted by `Int`?), and it's counterintuitive to anyone naively trying to use the returned object. I almost feel like I'd be better off writing my own wrapper class that conforms to the `RandomAccessCollection` protocol, except that I don't want to go down the rathole of implementing dozens of pass-through methods.

Is this really the most straightforward way to expose a Realm `List` (or some other `RandomAccessCollection`) as a read-only `RandomAccessCollection` with associated element and index types? Or is there some simpler generics- or type-erasure–based solution that I'm not aware of?